# jquery-ui selectmenu fix on screen when i scrolling

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, drop-down-menu, jquery-ui-selectmenu

On my site there is a panel (with vertical scrollbar) inside which elements  are located.

```
<div id = 'panel' style = 'width: 200px; height: 600px; overflow-y: scroll;'>
    <select id = 'select-in-panel'></select>
</div>
```

The jquery-ui menuselect is connected to the elements.

```
$('select-in-panel').selectmenu();
```

When I click on an item and a large drop-down list is expanded, it scrolls with the main window, not with the panel.

The drop-down list of jquery-ui selectmenu is fixed on the screen and does not move when I scroll the slider of the panel (div), but it moves when I scroll the slider in the main window (body). It seems to me that the parent of the drop-down list of jquery-ui selectmenu is the main window, not the panel.

**How to fix it?**

---

And second question:

Can I set the maximum size of the drop-down list box to scroll within this window if the list of items is large.

Now the entire list is displayed as a whole

Comment: If you can add fiddle, we can help better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify which element to append the menu to:

```
$('select-in-panel').selectmenu({
  appendTo: '#panel'
});
```

You can set the height of the drop down box so that it becomes scrollable when there is overflow:

```
$('select-in-panel').selectmenu("menuWidget")
  .addClass('overflow');
```

And then in your css:

```
.overflow { height: 200px; }
```

Refer to the documentation for more information and examples:
http://api.jqueryui.com/selectmenu

Answer (score 1):

Another way to handle this, which is often simpler, is to add class `.ui-front` to the parent to which selectmenu should be appended.  Note that this parent div will need to have `position: relative`, because the selectmenu div will have `position: absolute`

See: https://api.jqueryui.com/selectmenu/#option-appendTo

> When the value is null, the parents of the  are checked for a
>   class name of ui-front. If an element with the ui-front class name is
>   found, the menu is appended to that element. Regardless of the value,
>   if no element is found, the menu is appended to the body.